# Linux Mint Corners Musical Sequence Associative Array

Tags: shell-script, linux-mint, scripting, audio, associative-array

I am writing a script which uses **hot corners to play specific musical notes when hovering in corners, and depending on the musical sequence to execute a specific command.**

The script is called with parameter -d from bottom left, -e from b-right, -g from top-left, -b from top-right, appends the sequence in a file (for_hot) and compares the sequence with my associative array. Plays a succesful musical B'' when the sequence is recognized.

**2 issues:**

**Sometimes the commands won't execute;**

**I don't manage to poweroff.**

Here is the script

```
#!/bin/bash

#switch###############################
case "$1" in
-d) play -q -n synth 3 pluck 293.665 &
sleep 0.5
echo -n "d" >> ~/bin/for_hot;
;;
-e) play -q -n synth 3 pluck 311.127 &
sleep 0.5
echo -n "e" >> ~/bin/for_hot;
;;
-g) play -q -n synth 3 pluck 391.995 &
sleep 0.5
echo -n "g" >> ~/bin/for_hot;
;;
-b) play -q -n synth 3 pluck 466.164 &
sleep 0.5
echo -n "b" >> ~/bin/for_hot;
;;
esac
######################################

#midi mappings########################
declare -A commands
commands=( 
["egbd"]="firefox -n" 
["ebgb"]="idea" 
["ebb"]="notify-send "$instr "" 
["egdgb"]="echo pass | sudo -S poweroff"
["ee"]="nemo /home/mintbwoy");
######################################


s=$(<~/bin/for_hot);

for pattern in "${!commands[@]}";
do
echo "$pattern - ${commands["$pattern"]}";

if [[ "$s" == *"$pattern"* ]]
then
echo -n "" > ~/bin/for_hot;
play -q -n synth 3 pluck 932.328 &
var=$(${commands["$s"]});
$var;
notify-send "[$pattern] = ${commands["$pattern"]} "$var"";
fi

done
######################################
```